# WPF Development in Visual Studio Tools for Applications

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

It is possible to do WPF development (MVC, or MVVM) in Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012. I am trying to find the templates but they are not here. First day in a new place and I've never used this version before.

Any feedback would be great.
Cheers!

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have?  Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012 is not a stand-alone development product except when being deployed with an application that already integrates with it.

Comment: Seems like I have Visual Studio 2012, when I look at the "Help>About Microsoft Visual Studio" it notes that I have: Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012, Visual Basic 2012, Visual C# 2012, SQL Server Analysis Services, SQL Server Integration Services and SQL Server Reporting Services.  Hopefully that helps to clarify - thanks.

Comment: In the "About Visual Studio" dialog, on top of the "Installed Products" list box is the Visual Studio logo along with its full version number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio [Tools for Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Applications) is a development environment for application extensions, like SQL Server Reports, InfoPoint, Word automation, and some third-party LOB applications. It cannot make stand-alone Windows executables.

You want Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop, VS Professional, Premium, or Ultimate.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the reply. This is what I was thinking. I'm used to have Visual Studio Pro. I'm going to download Express for the time being and see about getting Pro for the future. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're going to get VS Express, make sure you get VS Express **for Windows Desktop**; VS Express for Web or for Windows Store cannot make WPF apps.

Answer (score 1):

Within Visual Studio, go to File -> New -> Project.  In the New Project dialog, choose Templates -> either Visual C# or your language underneath Other Languages -> Windows.  Then, you should see "WPF Application" in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking the same thing. I don't have the option for "WPF Application". As another noted below this is due to the version. I'm going to get Express down. Cheers.