# I have Visual Studio for my Business Intelligence tools, how do I add C# to it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, business-intelligence, .net-framework-version

Excuse the ignorance, but I've been a BI/SQL Developer all my life, and recently have been more interested in getting better with C#, I thought I'd fire it up and start playing with it. I thought it was supposed to be included in my Visual Studio package that I have for BI, but when I go to File > New > Project, a New C# project is not something that is available there. How do I add it?

Comment: When you go "File"->"New Project", do you see an "Installed" option in the left pane? Yes? Expand it to see the "Templates" item and have a look to see if there is a "Visual C#" item which you can expand.

Comment: The Business Intelligence tools do not include C#, or anything else beyond the Business Intelligence tools. Visual Studio is installed, but only for use as a shell. To do C# development, you will still need to install a "real" version of Visual Studio (Express or otherwise).

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Development in Visual Studio Tools for Applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611937/wpf-development-in-visual-studio-tools-for-applications)

Comment: Go to http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs and download the Community 2013 with Update 4

Answer (score 1):

Run the VS installation and add the required components, assuming that your VS package has them.

Comment: This assumes they have the correct version of VS. More than likely they are using a VS shell that shipped with SQL server which won't have that.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to reinstall a professional or premium version of VS. When you install select that you want all the packages so you can program in C#, VB, C++ ect.

here is a link to VS: http://www.visualstudio.com/

This link is a direct download link to a VS_Professional version download from the website:
[Vs Professional download link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/D/24D2DF27-E736-414F-BADC-77C0A0D6C1A8/vs_professional.exe)

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you install the correct version of Visual Studio.
But you can try instead the new  [Visual Studio 2013 Community with Update 4](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-community)

It is the latest IDE completely free with no license required that includes all the tools including C# development